# install PHPUnit_Selenium with pear into windows

Tags: selenium, window, phpunit, pear

Please, I am trying to install PHPUnit_Selenium with pear into windows, i am using this command :

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

but i get this error :

```
Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
install failed
```

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2014, phpunit installation via pear isn't available anymore.

*See* https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Alternatively, you can use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe) to install it.
After installation, open it and type

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.2.*"
```